# How to put space between switch button and its text in android?

Tags: text, element, space, between

I have the following element:

```
<Switch
    android:text="Data about client?"
    android:id="@+id/connected" />
```

But on designer the switch button and its text "Data about client?" are very glued together. I tried putting space between ? and " like that :

```
android:text="Data about client?    "
```

But I don't like that type of solution very much

Answer (score -8, accepted):

[image: In This pic]

Use tag `"android:thumbTextPadding"`

Comment: This is not the correct answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184365/4334743) is actually correct.

Answer (score 116):

I had the same issue, but for me the accepted answer of Sravan Sriram did not solve the problem.

What worked for me was the tag

```
android:switchPadding = "10dp"
```

> Minimum space between the switch and caption text. [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android:switchPadding)

Comment: `app:switchPadding="10dp"` worked for me for `SwitchCompat`

Answer (score 15):

Sure, kindly use this

```
android:switchPadding="5dp"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat` then use                 `app:switchPadding="8dp"`. This is work for me

Comment: And that's true for `com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial`